# Getting result from async call in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a list of offers that are fetched from an external service.

```
public void TriggerPurchase()
{
    List<string> offers = listener.GetOffers();
    Debug.Log("OFFERS " + offers[0]);
}
```

Here is the fetch function

```
public List<string> GetOffers()
{
    var purchases = GetComponent<Purchases>();
    purchases.GetOfferings((offerings, error) =>
    {
        if (offerings.Current != null && offerings.Current.AvailablePackages.Count != 0)
        {
            List<string> offers = new List<string>();
            foreach (var package in offerings.Current.AvailablePackages)
            {
                //Debug.Log("Package " + package);
                if (package == null) continue;

                offers.Add(package.StoreProduct.PriceString);
            }

            return offers; // Anonymouse function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value
        }
    });
}
```

I get the `Anonymouse function converted to a void returning`

I would like to get a list with offers?

**UPDATE

Adding the implementation of GetOfferings

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Callback for <see cref="Purchases.GetOfferings"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="offerings"> The <see cref="Offerings"/> object if the request was successful, null otherwise.</param>
    /// <param name="error"> The error if the request was unsuccessful, null otherwise.</param>
    public delegate void GetOfferingsFunc(Offerings offerings, Error error);

    private GetOfferingsFunc GetOfferingsCallback { get; set; }

    ///
    /// <param name="callback"> A completion block called when offerings are available.
    /// Called immediately if offerings are cached. <see cref="Offerings"/> will be null if an error occurred.
    /// </param>
    ///
    /// <seealso href="https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/displaying-products"/>
    ///
    public void GetOfferings(GetOfferingsFunc callback)
    {
        GetOfferingsCallback = callback;
        _wrapper.GetOfferings();
    }
```

Comment: Change the return type of GetOffers to async Task<List<string>> and you need to change TriggerPurchase accordingly

Comment: Given that the `purchases.GetOfferings` accepts a `Func<T>` (and is not void) you would have to return its result: `return purchases.GetOfferings(...)`. But it looks like the parameter is not a Func<T>. What is the signature of `purchases.GetOfferings`? And where is the async call you are referring to? Please post the implementation of `purchases.GetOfferings`.

Comment: @BionicCode I think the call is async because I'm using a library (RevenueCat) which calls Apple Store's api and pulls the configured products.

Comment: I don't see any async code. Anyways, your delegate is void and the GetOfferings is void too. How is a void method supposed to return a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void` methods don't return values. If you want your method to return a result you must change the type of the method and delegate:

```
public delegate Task<List<string>> GetOfferingsFuncAsync(Offerings offerings, Error error);

private GetOfferingsFunc GetOfferingsCallback { get; set; }

public async Task<List<string>> GetOfferingsAsync(GetOfferingsFunc callback)
{
    GetOfferingsCallback = callback;
    _wrapper.GetOfferings();

    return await this.GetOfferingsCallback.Invoke(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Now you can handle the expected result properly:

```cs
public async Task<List<string>> GetOffers()
{
    var purchases = GetComponent<Purchases>();

    // Return the result.
    return await purchases.GetOfferingsAsync(async (offerings, error) =>
    {
        if (offerings.Current != null && offerings.Current.AvailablePackages.Count != 0)
        {
            List<string> offers = new List<string>();
            foreach (var package in offerings.Current.AvailablePackages)
            {
                //Debug.Log("Package " + package);
                if (package == null) continue;

                await SomeAsyncApiCall();

                offers.Add(package.StoreProduct.PriceString);
            }

            // Because the delegate is no longer 'void'
            // you can now return a result
            return offers; 
        }
    });
}
```